# In PCR what is the chemical makeup of the primer? DNA or RNA?

Tags: dna, pcr, dna-replication, primer

I'm thinking the answer is RNA. Is that right?

Comment: You could improve your question by editing it to add _why_ you think/thought the answer was RNA.

Answer (score 1):

Almost always DNA. While RNA is possible, it’s much harder to synthesize (and keep stable) and DNA results in a purely DNA result that won’t need to be replaced with DNA later.

Answer (score 0):

> PCR primers are short pieces of **single-stranded DNA**, usually around 
>   20 nucleotides in length.

You can read more about PCR on [Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/science/biology/biotech-dna-technology/dna-sequencing-pcr-electrophoresis/a/polymerase-chain-reaction-pcr) or [Wikipedia](https://wikipedia.org/en/Polymerase_chain_reaction).